Prevent Ubuntu asking for password after waking up in 22.04
How can I stop Ubuntu from asking for my account's password I wake my computer up from a black screen? The ubuntu-lock-on-suspend setting doesn't do it.

Navigate to the Lock Settings: Go to apps > gnome-power-manager > lock.
Disable Use Screensaver Setting by Unchecking the option Use screensaver settings

Your answer is unclear to an average user. Kindly correct your grammar errors.
